# How to get the coordinate system from a PostGIS database?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system, srid

My question is probably amazinlgy stupid, but I can't find the answer myself.

I would like to extract from a database the latitude and longitude of points. For now, I'm getting x(the_geom) and y(the_geom), and I would like to know what is the coordinate system of the results I get.

How can I know this?

Comment: how to get coordinate of a point from the map to my database(postgresql) i wanted to draw a polygon or line and get the coordinates of this polygons from the oppenstreetmap to my database using javascript

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get the coordinate system of your table use the following:

> SELECT ST_SRID(the_geom) FROM your_table_name LIMIT 1;

For your second question, I am not sure if EPSG:4283 is by default defined in spatial_ref_sys table. In case it is not, you can use a INSERT command. This definition is from [spatialreference.org:](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4283/)

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 94283, 'epsg', 4283, '+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs ', 'GEOGCS["GDA94",DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_1994",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6283"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4283"]]');
```

Now use the ST_Transform(the_geom,4283) command.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was able to extract the SRID (900913).

Comment: I decomposed the question in two parts. The second part of the question is now available [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23483/problem-when-calculating-longitude-and-latitude-for-points)

Comment: Generally you would populate the table using `spatial_ref_sys.sql`, which also includes EPSG:4283 (SRID=4283 or GDA94 -- Australia) ... I honestly think you intended [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) ... furthermore, your instructions would require `ST_Transform(the_geom, 94283)` to work.